# Python: How to get a pages number using bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get a data-page from here

```
<span class="page-item mhide"> 
<a class="page-link active" href="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;">1</a>
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BuSearch', 'ClickOn_pagination_number', 'go_to_pagination'])"
class="page-link" data-page="1" 
href="/search/po_yers%5B0%5D=2003&amp;category_id=1&amp;marka_id%5B0%5D=28&amp;model_id%5B0%5D=262&amp;abroad=2&amp;
custom=1&amp;indexName=auto&amp;page=1&amp;countpage=20">2</a> </span>
```

I tried this, but it returns 1

```
def get_pages_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pagination = soup.find_all('span', class_='page-item mhide')
    if pagination:
        return int(pagination[-1].get_text()) # return the last element which is equal to pages number
    else:
        return 1
```

full code is [here](https://github.com/vcinonyx/Parsing/tree/master/auto.ria) and 
[link](https://auto.ria.com/search/?year[0].lte=2003&categories.main.id=1&brand.id[0]=28&model.id[0]=262&price.currency=1&abroad.not=0&custom.not=1&indexName=auto&page=2&size=20)

Comment: `page-link` element  is generated via JavaScript, which bs doesn't have, it doesn't exist on the source code. Try using selenium.

Comment: @CONvid19, thank you